# How to add wildcard subdomain A record with www prefix?

Tags: azure, dns

I have a multi tenant site  hosted in azure for which  I have added these A Records:

```
*.mysite.com      1.2.3.4
```

This way abc.mysite.com is working but www.abc.mysite.com is not working. How do I add entries for these records something like:

```
www.*.mysite.com     1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this add  individual subdomain entries for each of the subdomains
e.g

- www.abc.mysite.com     1.2.3.4
- www.abcd.mysite.com    1.2.3.4

One more thing, if you are on Azure you are better off using CNAME since the IP address is bound to change if your server for some reason is shutdown and hence deallocated.